# Minimum tx amount where amount = fee

Tags: transaction-fees, raw-transaction, dust, transactions

What is the absolute minimum amount which when transferred over a tx its value equals the tx's suggested fee? Is it the dust amount of 0.00005430 BTC? How is this value affected when that amount is the only unspent output spent in the tx and when there are more unspent outputs than just this one?

Relevant question:
[What's the minimum transaction with bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/whats-the-minimum-transaction-with-bitcoin)

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. When i try to broadcast a small transaction an error stating 'dust' is reported. What is the decimal number encoded into the client that triggers this? What is the magic number?

Answer (score 2):

There is no minimum amount. You can send 0.00000001 btc and even 0.0 btc without fees and there is a possibility that this transaction would be mined by some miner. But the probability is very low, because "standard nodes" (by bitcoin devs) do not relay such transactions.

You should add a fee if you want to send less than 0.00005xxx (I do not remember the exact value). The fee is 0.0001 per kb for clients running 0.8.x and 0.00001 per kb for clients on version 0.9.x

Here you can see transaction which transfers small amount of btc with a higher fee. https://blockchain.info/ru/tx/b07f23ce5d6a3746a3f8bd5202daa1084686812aa4ecce290208fbe84e68f564

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of these zero-fee cases, however I would like to know what is the miimum amount that can be sent for txs with a fee where that fee would be very close or equal to the amount sent.

Comment: Why not to try sending amount=1 satoshi with fee=1000 or 10000?

Comment: The amount sent and the suggested tx fee must meet at a given combination, I'm looking for that exact point.