# How do I know how many confirmations a transaction has?

Tags: transactions, confirmations

This is my first transaction and it's been since yesterday that I sent it. The website said wait for 4 confirmations then check email, but I haven't gotten any email so I don't know if it's gone through or not. Here's the transaction number and a screenshot of the transaction:
  2daf1bea238137e5db00cd12074a93f181bf86a759f1963fd92197671f32a463

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As you can see at the bottom of your screenshot, or on any block explorer similar 
(https://blockchain.info/tx/2daf1bea238137e5db00cd12074a93f181bf86a759f1963fd92197671f32a463),
you can see that it has 84 confirmations as of the time of writing, well over the 4 you said was needed.

Comment: So am i just waiting on them?

Comment: No-one here can help with your customer relationship to the website, you'll have to contact them if there is an issue :)

Comment: Remember to accept my answer if it satisfied your question :)

Answer (score -1):

Because of the size of the transaction and the exceptionally low fee amount, you can expect significant delays in such small transactions. This post covers it very well : [What's the minimum transaction with bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/whats-the-minimum-transaction-with-bitcoin)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question here :)